# How to change the color of avatar based on onclick in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have material ui avatar which take colors(pink/green) from styles.The problem arise when, i need to change the color from pink to green based on onclick. I tried to keep the color name in tate,but its not working,

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { green, pink } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import FolderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Folder';
import PageviewIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Pageview';
import AssignmentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Assignment';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  pink: {
    color: theme.palette.getContrastText(pink[500]),
    backgroundColor: pink[500],
  },
  green: {
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: green[500],
  },
});

class IconAvatars extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      color:""
    }
  }


  render(){
console.log(this.state.color)
const {classes} = this.props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Avatar className={classes.pink} >
       <div onClick=''>M</div>
      </Avatar>
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default withStyles(styles)(IconAvatars)
```

Its working fine with this code

```
  <div className={classes.root}>
      <Avatar className={classes.pink} >
       <div onClick=''>M</div>
      </Avatar>
    </div>
```

But I want to change  the color from pink to green based on onclick

Comment: Where do you have an onClick

Answer (score 2):

Set the state based on onClick event and dynamically destructure the appropriate color from the classes

```
class IconAvatars extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      color:""
    }
  }


  render(){
    const {color} = this.state;
    const {classes} = this.props;
    const AvatarClass = classes[color] || classes.pink;
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Avatar className={AvatarClass} >
           <div onClick={() => this.setState({color: 'green'})}>M</div>
          </Avatar>
        </div>
      );
   }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(IconAvatars);
```

[Sample demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-93qee)

Comment: I didnt get that...?

Comment: Which part? all we need to do is to set state to the desired color and then use the color from state to use the correct class from classes prop

Comment: I have also tried to set the state based on onclick..but its working

Comment: see the above implementation please

Comment: Fortunately it is that simple

Comment: so wat if ,i want to change the color back to other one on another onclick?

Comment: I added a demo. If you want to change from one to another you just have to update state accordingly.

Comment: Demo is also changing the color only once

Comment: I changed it to toggle. Its upto you what logic you want to have